# Always get 404 Not found while hosting a service in Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, rest, tomcat

I tried to build a Rest Service using Eclipse(MARS), TOmcat 8.x and Jersey 2.2.2
I have follwed so many links, or I have imported the projects itself. But when I run the project on the server, I always get 404 not found.

Links: (which I have downloaded sample)
https://github.com/kdmalviyan/RestWithJerseyExample
Reference:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yA77E.png]

> INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
>   Apr 26, 2016 9:09:21 AM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
>   INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [209] milliseconds.
>   Apr 26, 2016 9:09:21 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
>   INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
>   Apr 26, 2016 9:09:21 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig init
>   INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the Web app resource paths:
>     /WEB-INF/lib
>     /WEB-INF/classes
>   Apr 26, 2016 9:09:22 AM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
>   INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.19 02/11/2015 05:39 AM'
>   Apr 26, 2016 9:09:23 AM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules 
>   SEVERE: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
>   Apr 26, 2016 9:09:23 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
>   com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.(RootResourceUriRules.java:99)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1359)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:180)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:799)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:790)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:509)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:339)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:577)
>       at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1238)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1151)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1038)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4996)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> Apr 26, 2016 9:09:23 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
>   SEVERE: Servlet [Jersey Web Application] in web application [/CrunchifyRESTJerseyExample] threw load() exception
>   com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.(RootResourceUriRules.java:99)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1359)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:180)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:799)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:790)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:509)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:339)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:577)
>       at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1238)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1151)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1038)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4996)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> Apr 26, 2016 9:09:23 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: Marking servlet jersey-serlvet as unavailable
>   Apr 26, 2016 9:09:23 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
>   SEVERE: Servlet [jersey-serlvet] in web application [/RESTfulExample] threw load() exception
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1139)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:518)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:499)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:118)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1102)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1038)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4996)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Do I have to do any special configurations to run my Service on Tomcat 8.0?
Thanks in Advance.

Regards,
Learner.

Answer (score 0):

http://localhost:8080/RESTfulExample/rest/hello/World

Hit this URL according to your code
In web.xml only URL with rest/* will be treated as rest service and in your java class you have provided hello and after that you have to pass something {param}

and your output will be

Jersey say world

Comment: HI akshay, I have tried to hit the same url, but it seems no luck.

Comment: Hi Akshay, I tried to hit the same url, but no luck.